# Stored Procedure in Mysql returnig only one column data

Tags: php, mysql

Simple select stored procedure but getting only one column as the result others were getting as null.

Can somebody tell me where the error is..

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `p4`.`get_one_user_new`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `p4`.`get_one_user_new`
(
IN USER_ID INT(11),
OUT USER_NAME VARCHAR(255),
OUT FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(255),
OUT EMAIL VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
SELECT username,first_name,email
INTO USER_NAME, FIRST_NAME, EMAIL
FROM p4_users
WHERE id = USER_ID;
END $$
DELIMITER ;



CALL get_one_user_new('4',@USERNAME,@FIRST_NAME,@EMAIL);
SELECT @USERNAME,@FIRST_NAME,@EMAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a name conflict, you need to make sure your variable names do not clash with your column names.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `p4`.`get_one_user_new`
(
  IN PUserid INT(11),
  OUT PUsername VARCHAR(255),
  OUT PFirstname VARCHAR(255),
  OUT PEmail VARCHAR(255)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT username,first_name,email
  INTO PUsername, PFirstname, PEmail
  FROM p4_users
  WHERE id = PUserid;
END $$
```

Comment: Yes JOhan It Worked For Me But,
Unable to select all the three colums at a time
its giving a error.
    Query : SELECT(@PFirstname, @PUsername, @PEmail)

    Error Code : 1241
    Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Howevr the Individual queries works fine like
    CALL get_one_user_new(4,@PUsername,@PFirstname,@PEmail);
    #SELECT(@PFirstname);
    #SELECT(@PUsername);
    SELECT(@PEmail);

Comment: @NaveenKumar, don't use the `()` in the select, just do: `CALL get_one_user_new(4,@PUsername,@PFirstname,@PEmail); SELECT @PFirstname as firstname ,@PUsername as username ,@PEmail as email`